# Publishing map service with custom *.stylx symbology using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, symbology, arcgis-pro, map-service

I am using custom symbology with ArcGIS map services.

There are some styles available from ESRI called Military Symbology Styles https://solutions.arcgis.com/defense/help/military-symbology-styles/ defined with *.stylx files.

If it is possible to publish a map service both from ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro using the symbology defined in those styles, or are there any specific restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap makes use of `.style` files, where ArcGIS Pro makes use of `.stylx` files. They are not interchangeable between the two products. Although you can *import* [a .style from ArcMap into ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/styles.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2D13B0FBB19D49BC9296F958A0EC77D9).

There is also a `.serverStyle` file, that you guessed it, ArcGIS Server makes use of. I'm not 100% certain, but believe this file is only used in the ArcMap > ArcGIS Server publishing. I think the ArcGIS Pro > ArcGIS Enterprise publishing is different.

If there any limitations, I am not aware of them.